# I need to simplify $\sqrt[4]{x^{12}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to simplify

$\sqrt[4]{x^{12}}$

my answer is $|x|^3$ because the original radical is $|a| = \sqrt[n]{a^n}$ when n is even.

Am I wrong? Should the answer be $x^3$?

Comment: Set $x=-1$ and you'll see which result is wrong.

Comment: You are correct. $|x^3| $or $|x|^3$ note that $x^{12}$ is always positive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $12$ is an even number, $x^{12}$ will always be positive, even if $x$ is negative. Then, taking the fourth root we get the positive value of $x^3$.

Therefore, you are correct that the answer is $|x|^3$. Also as @Martin R suggests, you can set $x=-1$ as a quick check.